# Agda: Forming all pairs {(x , y) | x in xs, y in ys}

Tags: types, functional-programming, agda, theorem-proving, dependent-type

I'm wondering what the best way to approach list-comprehensions or cartesian products in Agda is.

What I have is two vectors, `xs` and `ys`. I want the (informal) set {(x , y) | x in xs, y in ys }.

I can fairly easily form this set using map and concat:

```
allPairs :  {A : Set} -> {m n : ℕ} -> Vec A m -> Vec A n -> Vec (A × A) (m * n)
allPairs xs ys = Data.Vec.concat (Data.Vec.map (λ x -> Data.Vec.map (λ y -> (x , y) ) ys  ) xs )
```

From here, I'd like something for getting a witness for pairs, something like:

```
pairWitness : ∀ {A} -> {m n : ℕ} -> (xv : Vec A m) -> (yv : Vec A n) -> (x : A) -> (y : A) -> x ∈ xv -> y ∈ yv -> (x , y ) ∈ allPairs xv yv
```

I don't know how to construct such a witness. As far as I can tell, I lose too much of the original structure of the vectors to be able to use my inductive cases.

I'm wondering

1. Is there something in the standard library dealing with this kind of "all pairs" operation, that would already have lemmas proved like this?
2. If not, how do I go about constructing pair witness?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've uploaded [a self-contained version of the code](https://gist.github.com/gallais/2e31c020937198a85529) with all the right imports to make it easier for you to play with the code.

What's important here is to see the structure of the final vector you obtain when running `allPairs`: you obtain `m` chunks of size `n` with a precise pattern.

- The first chunk is listing the pairs composed of the head of `xv` together with each one of the elements in `yv`.
- (...)
- The nth chunk is listing the pairs composed of the nth element of `xv` together with each one of the elements in `yv`.

All these chunks are assembled by concatenation (`_++_`). To be able to either select one chunk (because the `x` you're looking for is in it) or skip it (because the `x` is further away), you are therefore going to introduce intermediate theorems describing the interaction between `_++_` and `_∈_`.

You should be able to know how to select a chunk (in case `x` is in this one) which corresponds to this easy intermediate lemma:

```
_∈xs++_ : {A : Set} {x : A} {m : ℕ} {xs : Vec A m}
          (prx : x ∈ xs) {n : ℕ} (ys : Vec A n) → x ∈ xs ++ ys
here     ∈xs++ ys = here
there pr ∈xs++ ys = there (pr ∈xs++ ys)
```

But you should also be able to skip a chunk (in case `x` is further away) which corresponds to this other lemma:

```
_∈_++ys : {A : Set} {x : A} {n : ℕ} {ys : Vec A n}
          (prx : x ∈ ys) {m : ℕ} (xs : Vec A m) → x ∈ xs ++ ys
pr ∈ []     ++ys = pr
pr ∈ x ∷ xs ++ys = there (pr ∈ xs ++ys)
```

Finally, once you have selected the right chunk, you can notice that it has been created using `map` like so: `Vec.map (λ y -> (x , y)) ys`. Well, one thing you can prove is that `map` is compatible with membership proofs:

```
_∈map_xs : {A B : Set} {x : A} {m : ℕ} {xs : Vec A m}
           (prx : x ∈ xs) (f : A → B) → f x ∈ Vec.map f xs
here     ∈map f xs = here
there pr ∈map f xs = there (pr ∈map f xs)
```

You can now put all of this together and produce the witness by induction on the proof that `x ∈ xs`:

```
pairWitness : {A : Set} {m n : ℕ} (xv : Vec A m) (yv : Vec A n)
              {x y : A} -> x ∈ xv -> y ∈ yv -> (x , y) ∈ allPairs xv yv
pairWitness (x ∷ xv) yv here  pry = pry ∈map (λ y → x , y) xs ∈xs++ allPairs xv yv
pairWitness (x ∷ xv) yv (there prx) pry = pairWitness _ _ prx pry ∈ Vec.map (λ y → x , y) yv ++ys
```

Comment: One another way is to split the proof in two parts. The first part is `x ∈ xs -> y ∈ ys -> (x , y) ∈² xs ×² ys`, where `_×²_` returns a matrix instead of a vector. The second is `x ∈² xss -> x ∈ concat xss`. Both `_∈_` and `_∈²_` can be represented in terms of `Any`, so I suppose there is a scope for further generalization. If I were writing a library, I'd chose this approach, but for simple exercise it's probably overkill. BTW, it's not trivial to parse mixfix operators that contain sequences of ASCII symbols, like `xs` in `_∈map_xs`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused... what is the ∈ doing in the "there" case of pairWitness? I thought it was a type constructor, so I'm confused seeing it in a value position.

Comment: It comes from this mixfix identifier: `_∈_++ys`. I tried to give names to lemmas highlighting what they were doing but the lack of syntax highlighting in SO makes it quite hard to read. I'd suggest downloading the gist and having a look at it in emacs. Or I could edit my answer with renamed lemmas if you want.